# Clouds in cycles

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine

I am looking for a way to create something similar to the attached picture. I want to create clouds in blender using cycles. I found a tutorial on octane render for creating clouds in blender (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWN3lncHQxA).

But now im asking yall, if there is another way to do it without using octane render?

[image: artist: https://www.instagram.com/iammoteh/?hl=en]

Comment: This is not a great question to answer. You've linked us a 1+hr video (in Russian) and expect us to tell you, if this is possible in Cycles. This is **not** how it works. Try out everything the guy in the tutorial did **yourself** and see if it works in Cycles. If you're getting stuck at some point you're more than welcome to ask a more specific question in a new thread.

Comment: There is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPAYX8z9i8M
And some otherways as well but above should get you started quickly